# CakePHP element to display validation errors

Tags: validation, cakephp

I'm trying to display a summary of validation errors at the top of the form instead of next to each input.

I didn't see any built-in form helper to do this, so I decided to create a view element to do it. However, `$this->Form->validationErrors` isn't a flat array of error messages, so I can't just loop through it and print out the validation errors.  Here's a var_dump with just one validation error on one field:

`array(1) { [0]=> &array(1) { ["terrcode"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "Please enter a territory code." } } }`

So I can't loop through that without knowing the field names or flattening the array somehow.  There's got to be an easier way to do this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flattening the array seems to be the way to go, and fortunately CakePHP has a [Set::flatten](http://api.cakephp.org/class/set#method-Setflatten).

Here's the `errorSummary.ctp` I came up with:

```
<?php
$errors = $this->Form->validationErrors;
$flatErrors = Set::flatten($errors);
if(count($errors) > 0) { ?>
<div class="errorSummary">
<ul>
<?php foreach($flatErrors as $key => $value) { ?>
    <li><?php echo($value); ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to pass an array of fields to use to the element and then loop over them and call:

```
foreach($fieldsToShowValidationFor as $field) {
    echo $this->Form->error($field);
}
```

Pass the array via

```
$this->element('validation_errors', array('fieldsToShowValidationFor' => array('id', 'etc'));
```